# Unable to load video.js into Aurelia module using 'import'

Tags: aurelia, video.js

I'm working with Video.js, and am running into a problem when attempting to load the module using a standard ES6 `import`.

- I installed `video.js` using:
  `npm install --save video.js`.
- I'm    importing into my
  `video-player.js` file using:
  `import videojs from 'video.js';`

I'm getting the following error when attempting to load the page:

```
GET http://localhost:9001/dist/video.js.js 404 (Not Found)
```

Any idea why I'm seeing the `.js.js` extension, and why this is not working? This is the procedure recommended in the Video.js docs.

Answer (score 1):

Aurelia automatically adds the `.js` extension so you can remove that. Also, make sure you have correctly added video.js as a dependency to aurelia.json.  Is the location correct in `/dist`?

Comment: There is no `aurelia.json` file in this project. FYI, I started with the "aurelia-skeleton-navigation v 0.15.1" (for ES 2015). Also, this is referencing a file installed by npm, and none of those are moved into the dev-build (`/dist`).